# Hardware: Install pci-e x4 raid controller in pci-e x16. Will it work?

Tags: raid, pci-express

I am not sure, but if I install pci-e 4x raid controller in pci-e 16x slot, will it work?
As i read in google, it should work. What do you thinks/know?

Comment: To note: for PCI-express, usually x is placed in front of the number of lanes. 
For example, PCIe x4 is an interconnect thru four PCI-express lanes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It will work. It will only work at 4x though.

Comment: It would revolutionize hardware if you could make it work at more than the physically provided bandwidth.